# Print the collection of a dictionary

Tags: vba, dictionary, collections

I have created a dictionary that consists of multiple collections, but the only way I could find to print the content of the Items to a sheet in columns was:

```
    j = 0
    For Each key In dict
     i = 1
     For Each values In dict(key)
        .Cells(1 + i, 1 + j).Value2 = values 
        i = i + 1
     Next
     j = j + 1
    Next
```

Can I use something like `dict.Items` or a faster way to do it?

Comment: Might be easier to convert each collection to an array first. Arrays can be more easily written to the worksheet in a single step.

Comment: What do you mean by multiple collections (VBA Collections?).  Are you aware of the .Items method of the scripting.Dictionary (if that is what Dictory is?)

Answer (score 0):

this macro could help you.

```
Sub FillDictionaryWithUniqueValuesAndWriteToSheet()
  Dim Vardat As Variant
  Dim objDict As Object
  Dim lngRow As Long

  Set objDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

  With Sheet1

  Vardat = Application.Transpose(.Range([a1], .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)))

  For lngRow = 1 To UBound(Vardat, 1)
      objDict(Vardat(lngRow)) = 1
  Next lngRow

   .Range("H:H").ClearContents
   .Range("H1:H" & objDict.Count) = Application.Transpose(objDict.keys)

  End With

End Sub
```